# Django. Why do admin templates go in base folder instead of mysite?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm following the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/), and I don't understand why put the `templates` folder for the admin pages in the base directory, instead of having it in `mysite` directory.

In fact, when adding templates to the `polls` app, these were put in the `polls` directory.  Is there an underlying reason for this to happen?  Will I run into trouble if I change this configuration?

Comment: Per the tutorial **you just linked to**: *"Templates can live anywhere on your filesystem that Django can access. (Django runs as whatever user your server runs.) However, keeping your templates within the project is a good convention to follow."* If you want to put them in the corresponding app folder, go for it.

Comment: Could you give me some insight as to why it is like that?

Comment: Why what is like what?

Comment: Why they go in the base directory and not in `mysite`?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write the tutorial. Possibly so that they would only have to add one `templates` directory to the setup at that early stage. See also the next section of the tutorial (particularly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) and the reusable apps part (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/reusable-apps/).

Answer (score 1):

An issue I ran into once with putting templates in apps’ template directories was that the template loader would use the first template it found by looping through the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, so if your app comes after the admin app in the list (which it probably does), templates overriden there won’t be used.